# How do we do idle time processing in WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a way to do idle time processing in WPF application equivalent to OnIdle event in MFC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can dispatch a task (using the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) in the normal way) with a [`DispatcherPriority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) of `ApplicationIdle`, which will only be executed when the application is idle. Sample code:

```
DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle;    
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(priority, action);
```

Comment: I have put the code in the constructor and noticed that the task will is executed immediately when we double click the application. I am wondering where do I put my code that will execute whenever my application is not recieving any event or Message q is empty.

Comment: If the code is in the constructor you will want to dispatch the creation of the object (as above with ApplicationIdle priority) as the constructor will always run immediately on creation!    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(CreateMyObject), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle); Here CreateMyObject is a method that creates your object and Action is the delegate - it can include parameters, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

Answer (score 6):

It is the [Dispatcher.Hooks.DispatcherInactive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherhooks.dispatcherinactive.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

A late alternative answer (as a memo to myself):

```
System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle += (_, __) =>
{
    Debug.Print("Idle");
};
```